# json_encode is adding extra square brackets - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

json_encode is adding extra square bracket when I write code in to the json file using php.
METHOD to create & write JSON file.

```
function appendData($data){
$filename='data.json';
// read the file if present
$handle = @fopen($filename, 'r+'); 
// create the file if needed
if ($handle === null)
{
   // $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
   $handle = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
}

if ($handle)
{
    // seek to the end
    fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);

    // are we at the end of is the file empty
    if (ftell($handle) > 0)
    {
        // move back a byte
        fseek($handle, -1, SEEK_END);

        // add the trailing comma
        fwrite($handle, ',', 1);

        // add the new json string
        fwrite($handle, json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . ']');
    }
    else
    {
        // write the first event inside an array 
        fwrite($handle, json_encode(array($data),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
    }

        // close the handle on the file
        fclose($handle);
}
    }
```

Method call with data array argument

```
$file=  appendData($data);
```

Data

```
    $data= array(
    'name'    => "abc",
    'image_url' => "cdf", 
);
```

The JSON Output comes like

```
[[{"name":"Apple iPhone 6S\u00a0with FaceTime\u00a0- 32GB, 4G LTE, Gold","image_url":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51jV7zsrOtL._AC_UL436_.jpg"}]]
```

**Problem**: There are extra square brackets appending in json output, that seems fine becuase of  using `json_encode(array($data))` . 
But it doesn't parse on front end using javascript or jquery.

**Question**: how to parse this double square JSON data using jquery or how to append data properly in json file using php?

Comment: May be your data is already into json format.

Comment: data is in array format

Comment: Can you share that array and why this `array($data)` and this `. ']'`?

Comment: I have no problem doing `console.log(JSON.parse('[[{"name":"Apple iPhone 6S\u00a0with FaceTime\u00a0- 32GB, 4G LTE, Gold","image_url":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51jV7zsrOtL._AC_UL436_.jpg"}]]'))`, I get exactly the result you would expect.

Comment: @Nick But we cannot do this `console.log(result.name)` or how to parse and fetch the data to show in HTML from this json ?

Comment: If you _add_ an extra “array” layer before you encode this as JSON, you of course have to take that into account when accessing the decoded data again.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with your output. You are adding an unnecessary layer of array  by `json_encode(array($data))` but you just have to factor that into your JS when you try to access the values. You can access it as a 2-d array of objects as in this snippet:

```js
let json = '[[{"name":"Apple iPhone 6S\u00a0with FaceTime\u00a0- 32GB, 4G LTE, Gold","image_url":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51jV7zsrOtL._AC_UL436_.jpg"}]]';
let v = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(v[0][0].name);
console.log(v[0][0].image_url);
```